# Is there a command to change primary group for a new user in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

Is there a way to set a (new) user's primary group in Cygwin's `/etc/passwd` file without hand-editing the file?

I have a local group set up for members of the Dev Team on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box so that we can all modify a particular group files, but the regular users can only read them. As some of the work we do uses scripts that rely on Cygwin tools, this group is also in the `/etc/group` file.

When I need to add a new user to the "Dev Team" group, I add them in Server Manager, and then use `mkpasswd` to add that user to Cygwin's `/etc/passwd` file. Unfortunately, they get the regular Domain Users group assigned as their primary group and I then have to go in and edit the `passwd` file to change the group.

I now need to write some instructions for someone else who is not au fait with UNIX/Linux/Cygwin so that they can set up new Dev Team users and obviously "hand editing" `/etc/passwd` is a recipe for disaster if you don't know what you're doing.

So, is there a way of getting `mkpasswd` to set a different primary group, or another tool like Linux's `usermod` which can be used for the purpose of changing the group in a more controlled manner?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the solution I'm working with so far, using `awk` in a shell script:

```
# Extract group number for group from /etc/group
GROUP=$(grep "^${GROUPNAME}:" /etc/group | awk -F: '{print $3}')

# Create passwd entry for user and substitute extracted group number
# before adding to /etc/passwd
mkpasswd -d "${DOMAIN}" -u "${USER}" | awk -F: '{print $1":"$2":"$3":'${GROUP}':"$5":"$6":"$7}' >> /etc/passwd
```

(suggestions for improvements welcome - I'm not an `awk` guru)

It'd still be nice to find out (if) there's a "proper" way to do it, though.